# Batch file to copy 3 files to new directory

Tags: shell, batch-file, copy, batch-processing, xcopy

I have 100 Profiles that I need the cookies imported to a new folder, currently I'm using xcopy but is there a cleaner way to do it than this for the 3 files (Bookmarks, Cookies and Cookies-journal are the names)

Folders are named the same, I just need to copy the files from Profile 1 Directory 1 to Profile 1 Directory 2 - but 100 directories in order:

```
xcopy "C:\Users\Switch\Desktop\UserData\Profile 7\Bookmarks" "C:\Users\switch\AppData\Local\Chromium\User Data\Profile 7" /i /y
```

xcopy "C:\Users\Switch\Desktop\UserData\Profile 7\Cookies" "C:\Users\switch\AppData\Local\Chromium\User Data\Profile 7" /i /y

xcopy "C:\Users\Switch\Desktop\UserData\Profile 7\Cookies-journal" "C:\Users\switch\AppData\Local\Chromium\User Data\Profile 7" /i /y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time please give some kind of attempt, but, either way, a nested for loop should do the trick.

```
@echo off
for /l %%G in (0,1,99) do (
    for %%H in (Bookmarks Cookies Cookies-journal) do (
        xcopy "C:\Users\Switch\Desktop\UserData\Profile %%~G\%%~H" "C:\Users\switch\AppData\Local\Chromium\User Data\Profile %%~G" /i /y
    )
)
```

The first for loop, `for /l %%G` goes from `0-->99`,

The second indented one `for %%H` goes through each of the file names mentioned,

Then put the current profile number `%%~G`, and the current file `%%~H` into the xcopy command as they belong.

---

Note, the `for /l %%G` loop starts with a `Profile 0`, if this isn't desired, just use `(firstNumber,amountToAddEachLoop,lastNumber)` for example `(1,1,100)` to go from `1-->100`

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining, I was trying to piece together things for a few hours, but nothing is truly explained and I know nothing about coding and would love to try to learn more. Everything I find never has explanations on why what does what, so again thank you so much for helping actually UNDERSTAND what everything in the code you provided actually does!

Comment: No problem! `for` commands were hard for me to understand at first, but once i found out the basics of them i was unstoppable :D